# Tailwindcss absolute div in ablsolute

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I'm trying to use 4 absolutes in the div, but I couldn't quite understand why it went outside the div, where is the error?

[tailwind play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/bOSlX4F27J)

```
<div class="bg-blue-100 h-40 w-96 px-2">
  <div class="relative w-full h-full">
    <div class="absolute top-0 bg-blue-200 w-full">
      <div class="absolute left-0">1</div>
      <div class="absolute right-0">2</div>
  </div>
   <div class="absolute bottom-0 bg-slate-400 w-full">
     <div class="absolute left-0">3</div>
     <div class="absolute right-0">4</div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That second div with `bottom-0` gets positioned at the bottom of the container, and has a height of 0 - since its children are also absolutely positioned, they do not give it any height. You would have to position the children from the bottom as well.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add height to the parent absolutes

```
<div class="bg-blue-100 h-40 w-96 px-2">
  <div class="relative w-full h-full">
    <div class="absolute top-0 h-10 bg-blue-200 w-full">
      <div class="absolute left-0">1</div>
      <div class="absolute right-0">2</div>
  </div>
   <div class="absolute bottom-0 h-10 bg-slate-400 w-full">
     <div class="absolute left-0">3</div>
     <div class="absolute right-0">4</div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```